# Is it important to use savedInstanceState and onSaveInstanceState?

Tags: android, android-intent, parameters

I have an application which only supports portrait mode. I'm passing all my arguments using serialization, passing by means of intents - `intent.putExtra()` ant then in `onCreate()` -  `getIntent().getExtras().getX(MY_PARAM_NAME)`...

This works even when the system shuts down the VM, because of crashes related to other things. The activities seem to be started again with the correct parameters thanks to serialization.

So the question is, is save instance state necessary in my case? It seems to work well without it... didn't get any problems yet. But maybe I'm missing something, or didn't test enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've pointed out, if your `Activity` gets killed off (i.e. due to low resources), when it is recreated, it is passed the original `Intent` that started it. In your case, that means you get your serialized objects back.

Overriding `onSaveInstanceState` is important for the scenario where something has changed during the execution of your `Activity` (that hasn't been persisted elsewhere) that you would like to maintain in case it gets killed off.

For example, storing member variables in your `Activity` is dangerous for when the `Activity` is killed and recreated, unless you store them in the `Bundle` in `onSaveInstanceState`, and then restore them from the `Bundle` passed to `onCreate`.

**Update:** A great way to test the need for implementing that method is to force Android to kill your activities as soon as you leave them. Then, run your app and see if there are any problems. You can do this with the [Dev Tools App](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-devtools.html) on an emulator, or in ICS by going to Settings -> Developer options, and checking "Don't keep activities".

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Since all my data is derived from the parameters I guess I don't have to worry about it, for now. But good to know...

Comment: See my edit for a good way for testing whether or not you need to implement `onSaveInstanceState`.

Comment: That's also very useful and I'll use it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

`onSaveInstanceState()` and `onRestoreInstanceState()` are only explicitly called by Android when the Activity needs to be recreated, generally after a configuration change (ex. changing orientation).